# mysql statement not working: DELETE FROM user_info WHERE username='t2';

Tags: mysql

Hi I'm trying to delete a row from mysql using the primary key. I've looked up a couple of examples and exactly followed the syntax, but mysql table is not getting affected.

I'm using:

```
DELETE FROM user_info WHERE username='t2';
```

mysql reponse:

> Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
>   [Screetshot of mysql table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSs6R.png)

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: What Error has been showing?

Comment: @AjayKadoula Hi, the code is DELETE FROM user_info WHERE username='t2';  but its showing 0 rows has been affected.  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems you have single quote arount  t2 in db  `'t2'`
  then  try using

```
     DELETE FROM user_info WHERE username="'t2'" ;
```

or

```
   DELETE FROM user_info WHERE username like concat('%','t2', '%') ;
```

if you really have single quote saved in db arout t2  .. the you should avoid this kind of storage behaviour is really a bad practice store a value with (unuseful ) quote around

Comment: I need to delete rows from table whose column field has NULL values. 

I have used like this: 
DELETE FROM app_jobposition WHERE JobId = NULL;

I am getting Query Ok,. But rows are not affected.

Comment: @PrabhuVisu   for NULL values you need WHERE JobId IS NULL

Answer (score 0):

+----+------+------------+
| ID | NUM  | CREATED    |
+----+------+------------+
|  1 |   11 | 2018-01-01 |
|  2 |   22 | 2018-02-01 |
|  3 |   11 | 2018-03-01 |
|  4 |   44 | 2018-04-01 |
|  5 |   22 | 2018-05-01 |
|  6 |   44 | 2018-04-02 |
+----+------+------------+

DELETE from numbers  where ID = 1;

+----+------+------------+
| ID | NUM  | CREATED    |
+----+------+------------+
|  2 |   22 | 2018-02-01 |
|  3 |   11 | 2018-03-01 |
|  4 |   44 | 2018-04-01 |
|  5 |   22 | 2018-05-01 |
|  6 |   44 | 2018-04-02 |
+----+------+------------+